# PayPal Send Money API

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to send money or issue a non-referenced refund from the regular PayPal APIs?

I don't think we're enabled for MassPay, and our pre-existing system doesn't work with Adaptive Payments.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "not enabled for masspay" -- there are no restrictions on using Masspay. MassPay with n=1 payment is the usual way to do this. (PayPal also has non-referenced refund functionality, but that you do have to call & set up with them.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) (which is part of [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) and would require an App ID).

You could also use the [DoNonReferencedCredit API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoNonReferencedCredit_API_Operation_NVP/) if you're pushing funds back to a credit card that doesn't have an original transaction associated with it.

Comment: "Pay API" - "our pre-existing system doesn't work with Adaptive Payments"; all payments were made using PayPal accounts, not credit cards.